# AEM QueryBuilder Query

Tags: aem, dam

this is with regards to AEM DAM. I need to find out the count of original assets in specific path under /content/dam and their published status/count.

Is there a query to find out ?

Below is my query, not sure if it works?

SELECT * FROM [dam:Asset] AS r WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/content/dam/mySpecificpath]) and [jcr:content/renditions/original] and [jcr:cq:lastReplicated] is not null

I tried the below query and i don't see and I need a correct query to find out the count of original and their published count.

Comment: you cant have aggregation in aem jcr sql2, so count, sum (group by) etc not possible.

Comment: Can you give me a xpath or jcr sql2, or query builder query to fetch the count of original assets and their replication status